# Create Undo Option/Function After Delete Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, undo

I have a table with data which can be deleted if chosen. I want to be able to add an undo button that I can hit incase a row is accidentally deleted. I only need it to remember the last row deletion. I don't need it to remember everything. How would this work? I would preferably like the undo button to only be able to be displayed if a row has been deleted but if not that is okay...maybe just a `disabled` feature when no rows have been deleted yet and it can be `enabled` whenever a row has been deleted.

Here is what I have so far.

HTML/PHP:

```
<body>

<table id="html_master">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><button class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="delRow" name="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">  
</table>

</body>
```

Relative Javascript:

```
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");
    if (result) {
          var i=row.parentNode.parentNode;
          i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
 }}
```

Comment: Use CSS and hide it on the first delete. On a subsequent `delete` remove it then hide the requested delete.

Comment: Do you have some direction of how this code would look? Sorry, I've never really done something like this exactly before.

Comment: It'd be a JS solution, not PHP. PHP brought me here, sorry. If you have jquery you could use the `attr` function and set `display` to `none`. Not sure in vanilla javascript how to do it off hand though.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot undo the deleted row. i think you should make a new **table** with same columns named **deleted records** which row you select for delete first insert the record in deleted records table then delete it from main table and when you click on undo button then select the row from deleted records table and then insert it again in main table.